# Penal of User control going back side of parent panel

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, user-controls, panel

I have prepared one dropdown user control with a searching feature using textbox, panel, and checked listview.
when I click on down arrow PictureBox or in the displayed textbox, the listview panel will open as dropdown, and based on the mouse click I hiding and showing checked listview panel.

Now, when I put my user control within any panel and an open dropdown that time my user control's listview panel is going backside of the parent control/panel as I shown in the screen.

Please Help me.

[image]

Comment: The simple workaround is to use a *floating* control: the parent is set to `this.ParentForm` (property of a ContainerControl - if `this` is actually a UserControl) or *found* with the `this.FindForm()` method (property of `Control`, if this is a custom control - it's the exact same thing though). The reposition the *floating* control, since its coordinates are now relative to another container. This will limit the *floating* control to the bounds of the parent, though. See whether this is good enough. Otherwise, you can use a borderless Form or...

Comment: Hi Jimi,
Thanks for your quick response. I got that you are talking about to set the property of container control but I have some little confusion about which control I have to set property. So I can not catch you exactly what you are trying to explain to me. So can you please explain to me in detail so it will be good for us.

Comment: 1. You have a *fake* ComboBox with a *fake* ListControl. 2. You use a Panel as the container for the *fake* ListControl's Items. 3. This Panel is child of the UserControl or another container, still child of the UserControl 4. As a consequence, all child controls are constrained inside their inner Parent's (the UC) bounds => You need to set the Parent of the Panel used as *fake* container for the list Items, to the Parent Form of your UC (see the previous comment). => **Or** use a border-less Form instead of a Panel, so it can *float* even outside the bounds of the UC's Parent Form.

Comment: There are other means to accomplish the same result, using other types of controls (MenuStrips can *float*, for example).